# Parse string and total the positive & negative numeric components

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a string in an Excel cell.

Each row represents a sentence. This string represents a positive and negative score for a word in a sentence.

Sentences can be of any length, e.g.

> joy: pos=0.37 neg=0.0, honest: pos=0.4 neg=0.0, pick: pos=0.0 neg=0.0
>   hello: pos=0.0 neg=0.0, ok: pos=0.0 neg=0.0

I want to calculate the total positive and negatives in the cell.

Without splitting the string up with the text to columns feature in Excel, I don't know a possible way to do this with a formula.

An example of the output in this case would be:

> pos=0.77 neg=0.0
>    pos=0.0 neg=0.0

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that this whole line is in one cell: `joy: pos=0.37 neg=0.0, honest: pos=0.4 neg=0.0, pick: pos=0.0 neg=0.0` and you want a comma delimited sum of pos and neg in the next cell?

Comment: @Brian yes. Positive and negative totals can be in two columns if needed.

Comment: I would suggest you develop a VBA solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way but I believe this will work for you:

```
Function pos(rTest As Range) As String

Dim a() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim iVal As Double
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

a = Split(rTest, ",")

Dim iStart As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    iStart = wf.Find("=", a(i)) + 1
    iEnd = InStr(wf.Find("=", a(i)) + 1, a(i), " ")
     iVal = iVal + CDbl(Mid(a(i), iStart, iEnd - iStart))
Next

pos = "pos=" & CStr(iVal)

End Function

Function neg(rTest As Range) As String

Dim a() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim iVal As Double
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

a = Split(rTest, ",")

Dim iStart As Integer
Dim iEnd As Integer

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    iStart = InStrRev(a(i), "=") + 1
    iEnd = Len(a(i)) + 1
    iVal = iVal + CDbl(Mid(a(i), iStart, iEnd - iStart))
Next

neg = "neg=" & CStr(iVal)

End Function
```

I still consider myself new to VBA. I'm sure it could be optimized or tightened up a bit. Put the two functions in a VBA module. Then put `=pos` or `=neg` accordingly as a regular formula in the cell and put the range in.

Comment: I'm new to VBA too. I'm getting a expected end sub compile error

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you copy and paste the code in a regular module? It works for me if you keep your format in the cell (that is a comma delimited list of items).

Comment: It's not a subroutine. It is a function. `Function pos(rTest as Range) As String ... End Function`

Comment: I would have to see what you are doing to help you further. If you copy and paste the whole code above (you need to scroll to get all of it) it works with your sample. It also works with longer versions of your sample. Remember, you also need to use it as a regular formula in Excel (like SUM). Simply, click in a cell and put `=pos(YourRange)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegExp for quick parsing, ie

```
Sub Test()
Debug.Print StrOut("joy: pos=0.37 neg=0.0, honest: pos=0.4 neg=0.0, pick: pos=0.0 neg=0.0")
End Sub
```

*function*

```
Function StrOut(strIn As String) As Variant
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexMC As Object
Dim objRegexM As Object
Dim arr(1) As Variant

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "(pos|neg)=([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)"
    .Global = True
    If .Test(strIn) Then
        Set objRegexMC = .Execute(strIn)
        For Each objRegexM In objRegexMC
        If objRegexM.submatches(0) = "pos" Then
            arr(0) = arr(0) + CDbl(objRegexM.submatches(1))
        Else
            arr(1) = arr(1) + CDbl(objRegexM.submatches(1))
        End If
        Next
     StrOut = arr(0) & " " & arr(1)
    Else
     StrOut = "no match"
    End If
End With
End Function
```